# textFieldShouldBeginEditing runs code for condition that isn't met

Tags: ios, ruby, uitextfield, rubymotion

in my RubyMotion controller, I have 3 textfields. The last one, when tapped, runs the method didTapSomeField in delegate which pushes another controller. This textField cannot be edited like the other 2.

The problem: When I tab from nameField to emailAddressField or tab out of emailAddressField, it runs the method on the delegate didTapSomeField. I've triple-checked my first responder code and why if the textField doesn't equal someField, why is it still running what's in that if statement? Thank you for your help!

```
#
# method. textFieldShouldReturn
#
def textFieldShouldReturn( textField )
#---------------------------------------

    if textField == self.nameField

      self.emailAddressField.becomeFirstResponder

    elsif textField == self.emailAddressField

      self.didTapDoneButton

    end

end


#
# method. textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange replacementString
#
def textField( textField, 
               shouldChangeCharactersInRange: range,
               replacementString: string )
#----------------------------------------------------

  if textField == self.nameField

      true

  elsif textField == self.emailAddressField

      true

  end

end


def textFieldShouldBeginEditing( textField )
#--------------------------------------------

  if ( textField == someField )

    self.delegate.didTapSomeField \
           if self.delegate.respond_to?( :didTapSomeField ) 

    false

  else

    true

  end

end
```

I have also tried:

```
def textFieldShouldBeginEditing( textField )
#--------------------------------------------

  if ( textField == someField )
    self.delegate.didTapSomeField \
           if self.delegate.respond_to?( :didTapSomeField )             
    false

  end

  true
```

Comment: See this: http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/articles/debugging/. Also what is `someField`? It looks unassigned to me. Are you getting a NameError?

Comment: it's not a NameError at all, I rename fields sometimes when I post questions to sound more generic.

Answer (score 0):

Try replace responde_to by public_send